# How to assign a javascript function to a tabulator formatter rendered with php?

Tags: javascript, php, tabulator

I am using php to create the tabulator column definition array and I would like to assign a javascript function.
This does not work:

```
array_push($row2['formatter']='function(cell, formatterParams){var pType = cell.getValue();if(pType == "Patient"){cell.getElement().style.background = "yellow";}return pType;}');
```

I can assign the function to the array after using client side javascript. 
This works:

```
tdata[0][1]['formatter']=function(cell, formatterParams){var pType = cell.getValue();if(pType == "Patient"){cell.getElement().style.background = "yellow";}return pType;};
```

Any help making this work on the server side with php would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution... I'm sure there is a better way to do it!

```
function returnFunc(value, index, array){
        if (value['formatter']){
            if (value['formatter'].indexOf("function")>-1){
                return value['formatter']=eval("(" + value['formatter'] + ")");
            }
        }
}
```

```
tdata[0].map(returnFunc);
```